# Message not consumed and Seeking to offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm consuming message from Kafka topic but i continuously see below error message and my consumer is not able to consume message what could be the reason for the same.

'Seeking to offset 171 for partition mos_dev-0'

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. Many cases KAFKA logger writes this INFO, especially when you use KStream and Change Log topics. This wont stop your consumer from consuming messages.

LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer"; Seeking to offset 388466 for partition MyStream-KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000019-store-changelog-5"